# Firebase Hosting Rewrites to html route file

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

Is there a way to do something like this? I want to redirect to the html file with the same page route.

```
  "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/:page",
        "destination": "/:page.html",
        "type": 301
      }
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out, just add the `cleanUrls` property to firebase.json. As it says in [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config?hl=en#control_html_extensions).

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/:page*",
        "destination": "/:page",
        "type": 301
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
}
```